# Elasticsearch fielddata vs. fields mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

Can somebody explain me please what is the difference between settings fielddata and fields while mapping in Elasticsearch?
For example what is the difference between this two codes:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_field": { 
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": { 
            "type": "keyword" // for ordering
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
PUT my_index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "my_field": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true  // what is the difference?
    }
  }
}
```

Or can you tell me if this code does make any sence?

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_field": { 
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": { 
            "type": "keyword" // for ordering
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with those fields? What are you use cases? Do you have sample queries you'd like to do?

Comment: It is in comment. This settings are used for ordering or aggregations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the main intent is to do sorting and aggregations, then definitely use the first option, i.e. the `keyword` (sub-)field.

`fielddata` is the old-fashioned way of doing it and eats up a lot more memory.

You can find more detailed information and a link to a related article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332487/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-elasticsearch-doc-values/32332657#32332657)

Comment: And what about my third example? Does it make any sense? Also I didn't mentioned the text field is analyzed to the tokens with edge ngram tokenizer. Does it change something on this use case?

Comment: If you want to sort on `my_field`, you probably want to sort on the exact verbatim value not on the analyzed tokens, right? if that's the case, then you don't need `fielddata` but can simply sort on `my_field.keyword`... and yet still use `my_field` for full text search and other text-related use cases.